# Bootstrap ordering columns issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three divs and I want to know how to pull the third div to be the first one and the other divs take their original order.

The following two images are going to describe my point.

Here's the traditional way:

[image: Traditional Way of Aligning Columns]

Here's what I want to make: 
[image: What I need to make]

How can I achieve this layout using Bootstrap?

Comment: use `order` of CSS .

Comment: add your html structure

Answer (score 3):

Your items must be ordered in your html how you wish them to be ordered at the `xs` and `sm` breakpoints

View full screen:

```css
.item-1 {
   background: grey; 
}
  
.item-2 {
   background: green; 
}
  
.item-3 {
   background: orange; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
    <div class="item item-3">Item three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
    <div class="item item-1">Item one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
    <div class="item item-2">Item two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are fast :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap's [Column Reordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) Classes. Following `HTML` structure will make it possible.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
    Third Div
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
    First Div
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
    Second Div
</div>
```

```css
.div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.first {
  background: #7f7f7f; 
}

.second {
  background: #22b14c;
}

.third {
  background: #ff7f27;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
      <div class="div third">
        Third Div
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
      <div class="div first">
        First Div
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
      <div class="div second">
        Second Div
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 green">Item three</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 white">Item one</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 orange">Item two</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.green {
   background: green; 
}

.white {
   background: white; 
}

.orange {
   background: orange; 
}
```